# Can I set a format of data in colums to number:number?

Tags: sql, mysql

I need help regarding my sql project.

I have a table in which football results in column as VARCHAR. And I want to make it impossible to insert data into them other than in this format: number:number

For example: 2:1, 0:0, 10:0 and so on. Is it possible to set it to only this way?

Thank you.

Comment: Have separate columns for each team's number of goals. And never store numeric data in varchar columns, use a proper integer data type for integer data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it would be better to put the values in two separate `INT` columns. But if you really must do it this way, you can use a `CHECK` constraint to test the format using a regular expression.

```
CONSTRAINT CHECK (result REGEXP '^[0-9]+:[0-9]+$')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
ALTER TABLE football_results
ADD CONSTRAINT score_format CHECK (score LIKE '[0-9]:[0-9]')